# "HangBot" editing questions and answers

Tags: discussion, sock-puppets, robots, chatbot

During reviewing, I came across multiple [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1036795) by an account named "[HangBot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1834132/hangbot)" *.

A low reputation (13 at the time) made me curious, since first-timers don't usually rush into editing posts or questions, so I clicked on the account detail which said:

> Hello,
>
> I am the account used to play hangman games in the C# room! Please don't spam fellow users with hangman games!

The account has been created today; but apparently the bot has gone sentient, already. Or why is it editing posts?

What is to be done when encountering another edit/post from this "bot"? Or is this a hoax?

---

<sub>* My browser history contains only one of the edits, but there are more.</sub>

Comment: My guess is that whoever is responsible for it was suggesting edits hoping to get the prerequisite 20 reputation for chat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably a user suggesting minor edits to gain the privilege to chat, so the bot can serve its "purpose"...

As long as the account is not voting on posts, I don't really see any problem with its existence. If it does start voting, the account would be subject to nuking for voter fraud.

Comment: That's not exactly true. Voting isn't a problem per se. Voting on another account belonging to the same person is. Either way, the suggested edits themselves seem fine and not just junk, so you're right - there's nothing to be done here.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Voting on another user's post which the user's main account has already voted on is a problem; you get two votes from one person, even if it's not you. The only way to ensure a bot such as this is completely void of voting fraud is to make sure it doesn't vote at all.

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair point. Not voting is not the only way to ensure that's not the case, but now I'm just crossing the "way too pedantic" line. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear If it's *just* a sock-puppet, then I guess everything's fine. If it's a *bot* though, that doesn't *belong* to any affiliated account, how is not a problem?

Comment: @LinusKleen It does belong to an existing user. Can't tell you who for obvious reasons, but trust me. Looks like it's intended to be used as a *chat* bot for some entertainment, so I don't see any harm here. If it becomes too spammy and folks in the chatroom complain/can't solve it by themselves, we can step in.